# Run a C++ Application on a Webserver with WordPress

Tags: php, c++, wordpress

I have a C++-library (.so) for some calculations that I would like to call from Wordpress/PHP via an input formular. The promising idea to build the .so-library as a PHP extension using PHP-CPP has been fine locally on Ubuntu 14.04. But on the webserver this method failed because my webhoster doesn't support changing the extension directive in the php.ini/.user.ini. I see the following alternatives:

1. Build an exutable application and run it from PHP via `proc_open()` and send a lot of variables to the stdin of the application. Wordpress itself offers PHP plugins.
2. Redirect to another server where my own php extensions are supported.
3. Is there a way using python/web2py for that purpose?

Which would be best?
Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to create command line utility in C++ and execute it from php with `shell_exec`. I tried that in past and the performance was not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

> "Probably the simplest way is to create command line utility in C++ and execute it from php with shell_exec. I tried that in past and the performance was not too bad."

This did help. Finally I managed a build on Linux which was portable to the webserver where the website and wordpress are located. The call to the binary built from C++ was done with shell exec or popen in PHP (which one I don't remember, it was in 2018). The PHP code was finally migrated to an own wordpress plugin. Unforunately, I could not use PHP-CPP due to missing admin rights for the webderver. But the integration via shell exec or popen works fine.